# Why does conventional current work?

Tags: current

I have always been confused by why conventional current works even though we know it is the electron flowing that is causing the current. Like take the example below:
[image: schematic of a circuit with many lamps in series]

Which lamp will be the brightest if all the lamps are the same voltage also assuming that the wires have a small amount of resistance associated with them?

For if current was flowing from the negative to the positive (electron flow) then wouldn't A be brighter than B? But if conventional current was true then wouldn't B be brighter than A?

Comment: This question is based on incorrect assumptions. That assumption is that the lamps will be of different brightness. They are not. The lamps will be the same brightness. The reason this is the case (some really nitty gritty low-level physics which I only partially grasp...I think) is different from why conventional current works.

Comment: I think Bunda wants to know ***why*** and already knows what the books are saying about it. Likely taken from thinking that the electrons early in the circuit have `more energy` in them because they are just starting out on their trek through the circuit and will be `tired` by the end of it and just barely crawling back into the + node. Obviously, a wrong idea. But how to dispel it without just making arbitrary claims? Bunda, is that kind of it? Or do you not yet follow that the current must be the same everywhere in a series circuit?

Answer (score 2):

Kirchhoff's Current Law says that in a series circuits like you show, the current will be the same at all points in the circuit.

All lamps will pass the same current, so all will be equally bright.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, all the lamps will be the same brightness since the current through each lamp is identical (and assuming that when you say the "lamps are the same voltage" you mean that their resistances are the same). The voltage *across* each lamp will also be identical; the lamps don't "care" what their voltage relative to ground is, just what the voltage across their terminals is.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a length of pipe, and a bunch of partially closed taps installed at intervals along its length, and you inject 1 litre of water per second at one end the pipe, how much water should leave the other end, each second?

The answer is, of course, 1L per second. Any other answer would mean that somewhere along the pipe is a leak, or the pipe is ballooning and accumulating water, or something else along those lines.

If one molecule of water enters the pipe at one end, then (assuming the water is incompressible) a molecule of water must exit at the other end. The same principle applies to charges flowing along some conductive path; when an electron enters one end, an electron leaves at the other end.

This is the essence of [Kirchhoff's Current Law (KCL)](https://byjus.com/physics/kirchhoffs-law/), which (I paraphrase) says that the total number of charges entering a system each second, must equal the total number of charges leaving the system each second.

It will also help to know that "electric current" is a measure of how many charges pass some given point along a conductor, in some interval of time, in the same way that water flow is a measure of how many water molecules pass some point in some interval.

For your example circuit, if the same number of charges-per-second are entering the chain at one end as are leaving at the other end, this means that at all points along the chain, whether a measurement be taken inside the lamps themselves, or the wires that connect them, the measurement will be the same. Everywhere. Current at all points around that loop is the same.

Consequently, all lamps have the same brightness.

Right now, this instant, get it *out* of your head the idea that current somehow diminishes as it "travels" through a sequence of resistive elements. This is a misunderstanding of current.

*What diminishes is potential*, but that's another story. Suffice it to say that as charges move along the path, through the wires and lamps, their potential energy diminishes, meaning that at each junction between the lamps you will measure (with respect to some fixed potential, such as battery negative), a decreasing potential. If you wish to understand this better, then study Kirchhoff's Voltage Law (KVL).

In the water analogy, starting at the place where water enters, and moving towards the place where it emerges, measuring water pressure between the taps as you go, you will find that pressure drops by an some amount as you traverse each tap. You'll also find that the sum of all the individual pressure "drops" is equal to the total pressure difference between the two ends. That's KVL in a nutshell.

As for your reference to "conventional current", the algebra that describes electrical circuits makes no distinction between the polarity of the charges actually comprising the current. Mathematically, a negative charge flowing one way is equivalent to a posititve charge flowing in the opposite direction.

The fact that in most circuits current is comprised of moving electrons, *negative* charges, does not change the result of any of the maths involved in describing it. You could consider a ball falling as having a positive velocity downwards, or a negative velocity upwards, the two descriptions are mathematically equivalent.

Sadly, to the confusion of beginners today, when the electron was discovered, it was arbitrarily assigned to be negatively charged, and that stuck. It made sense at the time, I'm sure, but as modern engineers we decline the old-timers' ways, preferring instead to pretend the charges are positive, falling from higher potential to lower, even though we know that's not true.

The mathematics still works, and this "conventional current" is so much easier to envisage; it's a lot more intuitive to think of positive charges "falling" in an electric field, since everybody is already very familiar with the concept of positive masses falling in a gravitational field.